# Mismatch Error on Duplicate Method

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying to implement some vba code in excel 2007 to copy a chart(chart object), then move it to another sheet.  I'd worked a way to do this fine, but when encountered some issues in 2010.  I've since turned to using the chartobject.duplicate method to create the copy, but am running into a mismatch error.  The program does infact duplicate the chart but still gives an error.

```
Dim w As Double 'The width of the new table
Dim h As Double 'The height of the new table
Dim cht As ChartObject



    Worksheets("Charts").ChartObjects("OT DAY").Activate
    Set cht = Worksheets("Charts").ChartObjects("OT DAY").Duplicate
    cht.Name = "Chart 1"
    Worksheets("Charts").Charts("Chart 1").Location xlLocationAsNewSheet, curMod
```

The error occurs when I set cht to the objectchart duplicate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cht As Shape 'not ChartObject
```

Comment: `Shape` works but [documentation says `Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject.duplicate#return-value). So maybe there is some exception when returned object is other than `Shape`.